# Date header from the request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, header, asp.net-core-2.0

How could i get the date when the request to server was firstly created by a client?

*Client send GET/POST request to server -> On the server side I extract Date when the request was sent*

There is a property in `HttpContext.Request.Headers` called `HeaderDate` but it's always empty in every request.

[Here](http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/refdocs/http/group__http__date.html) is a description of an exact header that I want to get on the server side.

P.S. I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the network is very poor, it's likely the request was created no more than a second or two (at most) before it reached your server. How accurate do you want to be, exactly?

Anyway it's up to the client whether they send you any information like that. In fact the spec at https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html says

> Clients SHOULD only send a Date header field in messages that include
>   an entity-body, as in the case of the PUT and POST requests, and even
>   then it is optional. A client without a clock MUST NOT send a Date
>   header field in a request.

So in other words it's actually recommended not to send this header in many cases. A GET request will almost certainly never include it for instance, unless the client in question is going against the stated recommendation.

You're probably better off just using the time the request reached your server, and treating that as good-enough.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I thought this task is a quite trivial one.. Actually, my client got a timer on his side, and i want to be sure if he send his POST in the set time scope, or not. Because if he sends it at time, but his connection will fail with 5+ secs, i will treat this request as it shouldn't be :)